# Can you explain me how the IntentService works

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask, intentservice

I have an `IntentService`that executes CRUD operations. I start the `IntentService` when my app starts to update data, when the data has been updated I need to start an `Activity` that shows the data.

But as i see now, `IntentService` starts my code in a separate process, that finishes after my activity is created, so i have empty activity. Can i fix this? Or standard `Service`is the only way?

```
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.e("action",intent.getStringExtra(Utils.INTENT_SERVICE_INVOKE));
        ResultReceiver resultReceiver = intent.getParcelableExtra(Utils.RECEIVER);
        switch (intent.getStringExtra(Utils.INTENT_SERVICE_INVOKE)){
            case Utils.LOAD_All_DATA:{
                loadActivities();
                loadPersons();
                loadPictureData();
                Log.e("order","forth");
                resultReceiver.send(Utils.TASK_FINISHED,new Bundle());
//                Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
//                broadcastIntent.setAction(Utils.LOAD_All_DATA);
//                sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
                break;
            }
            case Utils.READ_ACTIONS_DATA:{
                readActionData();
                break;
            }
            case Utils.READ_PERSONS_DATA:{
                readPersonsData();
                break;
            }
            case Utils.READ_ACTION_BY_ID:{
                readActionDataById(intent);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation? It's here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

Comment: @Christine Yes i did, there is no answer to my question.

Comment: The documentation has a paragraph about sending Notifications, which is one way to start an Activity that retrieves the results your IntentService has create, it also has a paragraph on callbacks, which is how a service reports back to an Activity if your app is active. Generating a notification is the way to go if your app is not in the foreground.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. "How can I fix this", but I don't see from your "question" what needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IntentService` does not start in separate process by default. It is a regular `Service` with the addition of logic that delegates execution of work to a single background thread and stops the service once all incoming `Intents` had been handled.

You want to do the following:

1. Perform data update from the web server
2. Notify once update completed
3. Get a reference to updated data from `Activity`

Your options are (from the top of my head):

1. Use standard android `Service` which can be both started and bound. Start this `Service` when update required, send notification when update completes and bind the `Service` from `Activity` in order to get the data.
2. Implement some in-memory cache which is neither tied to `IntentService`, nor to `Activity`. For example: implement `DataManager` class and instantiate it in `Application`. Both the `IntentService` and `Activity` can get a reference to `Application`, therefore they will be able to get a reference to `DataManager` object. `IntentService` will write the data into it, and `Activity` will read this data later
3. Implement data cache SQLite. This approach is very similar to #2 above, but data is not stored in memory, but written into SQLite database.

The easiest amongs the three options above is #2. Furthermore, if you go with #2 then it will be relatively easy to migrate to #3 if such a need arises (which is the best for "data heavy" apps).

Comment: Thx, i think il try to go for Service solution(used it before), i have twisted the process word value, i was speaking about thread, sry. Sadly we can't realy get some kind of task_finished callback from IntentService, it would be awesome tool too use, if they were implemented.

Comment: @Turbozanik, you can use event bus in order to perform communication between component in your app. My favorite event bus is Green Robot's event bus. Using these tools you can easily communicate events from `Service` to `Activity`, `Fragment`, `Application`, etc.

Comment: i am using ResultReceiver, but il reed about Green Robot's. Thanks.